# Typescript: Asynchrony problems with axios get, file write, and file read

Tags: typescript, firebase, asynchronous, axios

I'm writing a Firebase Cloud Function that downloads a file, writes it to /tmp/, and then attempts to parse it as a Docx file with the docxtemplater package. I intend to do some more processing of that file once this is up and running, but that's beside the point.

My problem what I've written so far *usually* works, while at other times I get the following error:

```
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/template_file'`
```

When this error pops up, running hitting the function again will usually just fix the problem outright and start returning successes.  I can then spam the function and I'll end up with a bunch of different successes without failures. This makes me suspect two problems:

1. My code isn't correctly handling the asynchronous parts of the axios get, write, and read.
2. Weird caching behavior is taking place with Firebase functions. Then again it's totally possible that (1) is fully at fault here. In other words, the first time the code is ran, the file read is taking place before the initial download is complete (not exactly sure why this is happening -- perhaps I'm misusing await / promises?), while follow-up functions runs are succeeding because the file is already downloaded. Then again, if that were true, that'd go against my assumption that each run of a Firebase Cloud Function is independent.

I feel I'm missing something super obvious here. Any ideas?

The code in question is:

```
exports.fillTemplate = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        await downloadTemplateFile(data.docxTemplateDownloadUrl, localFilePath);
    } catch (e) {
        return buildErrorResponse('500', 'Unable to download file: ' + e);
    }

    var docx;
    try {
        docx = await readDocxFile(localFilePath);
     } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return buildErrorResponse('500', 'Unable to interpret docx \' file: ' + e);
    }
    
    return buildSuccessResponse();
}

function readDocxFile(filePath) {
    try {
        var content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');
        var zip = new PizZip(content);
        var iModule = inspectModule();
        var doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, { modules: [iModule] });
        return doc;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

function downloadTemplateFile(downloadUrl, tmpFilePath) {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: downloadUrl,
        responseType: 'stream',
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            console.log(error.request);
        } else {
            console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        console.log(error.config);
        throw error;
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Info: Received response for axios get");
        response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFilePath));
        console.log("Info: Successfully wrote to " + tmpFilePath);
    });
}
```

Comment: `await downloadTemplateFile(data.docxTemplateDownloadUrl, localFilePath);` seems to indicate that the `downloadTemplateFile` function returns a promise. However... look closely at your code. The `downloadTemplateFile` in fact lacks a return statement and so is implicitly returning `undefined` (and additionally does not wait for the process it kicks off to finish because of that).

Comment: This was right on the money. Much appreciated.